# Translate a control point in FontForge

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I'm making my first steps with FontForge editing an existing font. I'd like to use the lower curve of the lower-case T and apply it to the lower-case L to make it more distinguishable from the upper-case I. But it needs to be a little shorter there.

So I'm going to move the right end of that curve to the left, and then compensate the curve by moving their control points back to the right. I know how I can translate the curve points exactly with the transformation dialogue. But it doesn't handle control points at all. I can't even select them alone.

Is there a way to translate bézier curve control points in a controlled way without having to move the mouse manually to exactly the right point, looking at the coordinate numbers and axes? I'll have to do that for several styles so I'd like to automate much of it as far as possible without introducing new errors.

Here's a visual explanation of what I mean. The green curve points need to go left. Easy. And the blue control points need to go right. Hard.

[image: Screenshot with explanations]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Ourpool of fontforge users is pretty thin these days so you miggt need to wait for an answer for a while. Or your welcome to answer once you sort this trough some other means meanwhile. Also i dont thonk pixel is a meaningful unit for a font.

Comment: Oh, yes, not pixel. I think the positions there are unitless. Also, can you recommend other support sources for FontForge? I couldn't find any!

Answer (score 1):

In this case it sounds like it would be much easier, and also more precise, to insert two new points and remove the old ones.

- Select the *Pointer* tool.
- For each of the two points:

  - Left-click a spline to select it.
  - Right-click the spline and choose *Insert Point On Spline At*.
  - Input the X coordinate where you want to add a point.
- Select the two original points.
- Right-click the selection and choose *Merge to Line*.

[image]